# Sitecore Experience editor error in xm cloud partial design

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, experience-editor

Looking for help on solving `Experience editor` error in xm cloud.,
We are using `xm cloud + next js` to build a website.
Experience editor is not opening to do edits for partial design, whereas it is opening at the home page level, which again refers to partial design via page design selected.

- Error: Connection to your rendering host failed with the following error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
- the rendering host settings and reference updates in the site setting level were added as expected. (We tried deleting the default and checked once it auto-created)
- Even an empty / newly created partial design gives the same error when opening in the experience editor
- Used https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head-staging as a base solution to set up the instance.
- We saw an error like this in the rendering container - processTicksAndRejections
- And following the https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/troubleshooting-jss-next-js-apps.html and no luck
- Graph QL, Layout service gives output JSON for the partial design as expected.
- We tried recreating the new environment using the same branch and still issue exists

Please provide input for resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you please share detailed logs?

Comment: there is a react component issue in the head app. Investigating the same

Comment: Sure @Alexander let me share some time.

Comment: I observed a scenario: If we add the same header/footer partial design final layout raw value to any page type item final layout it opens up.
if we inherit instead of _base partial design template in partial design template to page type template. it opens in EE                                                                                                   Considering that maybe the partial design template was corrupted, took a package from a working SXA headless project and installed it, but that not helped.

Bug in sitecore? I added a ticket to see the support team's input.

Comment: @Alexander                                                                                     
 27976 07:37:42 ERROR [JSS] Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host: `https://xmc-<id>.sitecorecloud.io:443/api/editing/render`
27976 07:37:42 ERROR The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
34444 12:50:51 ERROR [ExperienceEdge Publishing]: Failed to upload media blob for media item 58514459-3d7a-4159-8275-cd7d6d4b2cb8

Comment: 38168 14:08:56 ERROR MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered. The expected hash value: D9AE3CECDE375AD1AB936723F43E625C. Media URL: /-/media/Project/<Value>/<Value>/<Value>.png?h=49&iar=0&w=274, Referring URL: https://xmc-<id>.sitecorecloud.io/?sc_itemid=%7B00130951-EB9F-4C88-9D6D-A13D46AF7F87%7D&sc_site=<Value>&sc_mode=preview&sc_duration=temporary&sc_device=default&sc_lang=en

Comment: please make sure that mentioned URL below is valid: 
https://xmc-<id>.sitecorecloud.io:443/api/editing/render
Most likely you should use something different instead of <id>

Comment: there it will replace the client project id. that is validated. it's correct.